# Error when serialize List<string>

Tags: c#, serialization, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

A am developing a Windows Phone Runtime application and a I have data in a string list. But when I suspend my app the error occurs `Error trying to serialize the value to be written to the application data store` and `Additional information: Data of this type is not supported.` it says that string list is not supported, does any one know how I fix it?

OnLaunched:

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
       if (ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values.ContainsKey("lista"))
       {
          lista = (List<string>)    (ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["lista"]);
       }       
}
```

OnSuspended:

```
private async void App_Suspending(object sender, Windows.ApplicationModel.SuspendingEventArgs e)
    {
       ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["lista"] = App.lista;
    }
```

App.lista is a list declared at app.xaml.cs like `public static List<string> lista = new List<string>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must serialize/deserialize the list yourself, for example:

```
string Serialize(List<string> list)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (string s in list)
    {
        result.AppendFormat("{0}{1}", result.Length > 0 ? "," : "", s);
    }

    return result.ToString();
}

List<string> Deserialize(string s)
{
    return new List<string>(s.Split(','));
}
```

If your strings might contain commas, code accordingly.